# Box iOS SDK - Receiver 'BoxSearchRequestBuilder' for class message is a forward declaration

Tags: ios, sdk, box-api

I am trying to use the BoxSearchRequestBuilder class to be able to perform a search in Box via the iOS SDK (v2). When I try to instantiate a BoxSearchRequestBuilder instance with its initializer, I get a compiler error.

What I am trying to do:

```
BoxSearchRequestBuilder* builder = [[BoxSearchRequestBuilder alloc] initWithSearch:@"123" queryStringParameters:@{@"content_types" : @"tags"}];
```

The error:

`receiver 'BoxSearchRequestBuilder' for class message is a forward declaration` or
`receiver type 'BoxSearchRequestBuilder' for instance message is a forward declaration`.

Basically the BoxSearchRequestBuilder class is declared via a forward declaration (@BoxSearchRequestBuilder), so I cannot directly access its properties/initializers.

I can fix the error by going to the iOS SDK class `BoxSearchResourceManager` and changing the forward declaration to an import statement:

```
#import "BoxSearchRequestBuilder.h"
//@class BoxSearchRequestBuilder;
```

However, I don't think I should be doing this. Are there any other alternatives? The rest of the API works fine.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Here is the fix for you https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk-v2/commit/67064ea1f0c1aff040fba1e249b9f550281c01e2

I'd encourage you to file issue on SDK github page, or even make similar changes and make pull request. Thanks for flagging this one!

Comment: Thanks Boris, it is looking good. Do you want to answer the question as well and we can close this one?

Comment: no problems. just replied as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for flagging this.
It has been fixed thanks to your feedback in this change:
https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk-v2/commit/67064ea1f0c1aff040fba1e249b9f550281c01e2

feel free to file issues on SDK github page.